# user module - node js

Tags: object, node.js, module

i have a question regarding defining objects in modules.

lets say i have a module:

```
/*---obj----*/
function A (param){
this.parm=param;
function func(){
//do somthing
 }
}
exports.func=func;

/*---file.js----*/
obj=require('obj');

function fileFunc(A){
A.func();//with out this line it works fine
A.param=2;
 }
}
```

for some reason it does not recognize the function in the object A. it recognizes the object A and its different vars, but when it comes to executing the function it gives the msg:
     TypeError: Object # has no method 'func'

i tried also to export the function in A by:
     exports.A.func=A.func

or
     exports.func=func
neither works..

does someone have a clue?

thanx
matti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you defined inside of A is local only to that function. What you want is

```
function A(param) {
  this.param = param;
}

A.func = function() {
  // do something
};
```

But if you are treating A as a constructor then you'll want to put that function in A's prototype

```
A.prototype.func = function() {
  // do something
};
```

Comment: thanx allot that worked!

but there is still one problem. 
the object A also gets a socket object, in other words lets say that the param is a socket (using net module) . in the function func i want to write to the socket. so i write
A.prototype.func = function() {
  A.write('str');
};

it does not recognize that this a socket. it says that the function write is unidentified. how do i tell the compiler that param is an object of type socket?

Comment: When you instanstiate an object in Javascript, you can access it's properties with the `this` variable. What you want to do is `this.param.write('str');`. I might be a good resource on learning how to work with objects in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: i am sorry for not writing it, but that is what i wrote. 
i wrote this.param.write('str')
and the error says that "cannot call method 'write' of undefiend"

Comment: Then I'm guessing you're not instanstiating the object `A`, and you need to use the first example I used in my answer. `A.func = function() {};` instead of adding `func` to the prototype.